# Vinyl printing at home?

Tags: print-design, branding, print-production, vinyl

I'm looking to invest into a vinyl machine that would allow me to print stickers for my brand.

I have a few questions on how it works, and overall pricing:

1. If I want to print onto a clear vinyl with black ink, would I just buy a clear vinyl roll that fits a machine?
2. I'm still relatively small scale, would one of the [$300 bundles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CDQGCTW) from Amazon work for what I need? I planned to cut each sticker separately with an x-acto afterwords, so if I can't do di-cuts, that's fine.
3. Does quality of a printer affect quality of my image? I'd be printing an eps/vector file, but could the printer itself make my image fuzzy?

If this isn't the best value for what I'm trying to do, is there a better solution? Or should I just stick with outsourcing this to a site like sticker robot?

Comment: Your link is to a vinyl cutting machine, not a vinyl printing machine.

Comment: @BillyKerr If I needed transparent stickers, would you recommend a vinyl cutter over a printer? Did some research and came across the differences.

Comment: Not if you need to print on them.

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely stick with a company you outsource if it is just for your brand.  Once you get into the nice machines it gets pricey and not worth it to DIY.